Controlling Customtkinter from a Thread
I want to deactivate and activate CustomTkinter buttons from the thread. But the buttons are deformed (image artifacts appear). Why does this happen and how to solve the problem?


I expected smooth buttons without deformations
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter
import threading

def function():
    tabview.configure(state='disabled')
    # here is other code.....
    tabview.configure(state='normal')
    root.update

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")
root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("465x235+300+200")
root.resizable(False, False)

tabview = customtkinter.CTkTabview(root, fg_color='#242424')
tabview.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

tab_1 = tabview.add("Tab_____1")
tab_2 = tabview.add("Tab_____2")
tab_3 = tabview.add("Tab_____3")
tab_4 = tabview.add("Tab_____4")

thread_ops_directory_read = threading.Thread(target=function)
thread_ops_directory_read.start()

root.mainloop()


After the program is launched, a file reading operation is performed in the thread. Until this operation is completed, the buttons should be inactive.

there is no deformation when i checked

What system do you have? I have Windows 10, deformation is present. Without threads there is no deformation. But I need threads

deformation is not always observed, but in most cases it is present. This is a small example. If there are many buttons, then there are many cases of deformation. I supplemented the second screenshot in the post

As you already find out that the deformation issue is due to the update is performed in a child thread, so you can make the update in the main thread instead by using .after() inside the threaded function to schedule the update in the main thread.
Also if function() will be called when starting the program, you can disable the tabview initially instead of inside function():
...

def function():
    # here is other code
    ...
    # schedule the task to be executed in the main thread later
    tabview.after(1, lambda: tabview.configure(state='normal'))

...

tabview = customtkinter.CTkTabview(..., state='disabled') # disable initially
...



Thank you. It works. But to disable (or enable) many buttons, you need 1 line for each button. To reduce the number of lines, I tried a loop, but it only works for the last button from the list. Why doesn't it work for all buttons from the list?

def function():     for i in [btn1, btn2, btn3, ..., btn_last]:         i.after(1, lambda: i.configure(state='disabled'))     # here is other code     ...     for i in [btn1, btn2, btn3, ..., btn_last]:         i.after(1, lambda: i.configure(state='enabled'))

It is better to use another function to enable/disable the buttons and use .after() to execute that function.

Thanks for your help. My problem is solved.
